Is there a strategy to simulate "typing" status with WhatsApp Cloud API using Node.js?
I am developing a chat application that interacts with users via the WhatsApp Cloud API. The idea is to show the "typing" status when the user is writing, but I can't find a way to implement this.
I am using Node.js for the application and integrating with the API, but I don't see any clear example of how to display the "typing" status. So far, I have been able to send messages successfully, but the typing indicator part is still a challenge.
Here is a basic example of how I am setting up the API with Node.js:
const axios = require('axios');

const sendMessage = async (recipient, message) => {
    const url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{your_phone_number_id}/messages';
    const data = {
        messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
        to: recipient,
        text: { body: message }
    };
    const headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {your_access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, data, { headers });
        console.log('Message sent successfully', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message', error);
    }
};

sendMessage('recipient_number', 'Hello, this is a test message!');

I would like to know if anyone has experience sending the "typing" status (typing indicator) using the WhatsApp Cloud API with Node.js. How can I do this?
Some ideas I’ve considered:

Sending a quick, empty message to trigger the typing indicator.
Using a delay before sending the actual message, mimicking typing time.

Has anyone implemented this or found a better approach? Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for any help!

This question is similar to: Whatsapp Cloud API- How to get the typing Indicator status?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
